# Wrapfig bug when immediately followed by citation

Tags: citing, wrapfigure

I noticed that with `wrapfig`, if the first text is a citation or cross reference, `wrapfig` ignores the entire paragraph and the paragraph spools over the top of the image.

Don't ask me to put a full MWE up, as I have deadlines and don't have the time now, but if someone knows what I am talking about, feel free to chip in.

Basically something like this should reproduce.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
.... image code whatever
\end{wrapfigure}
\citet{key} published bla and bla and the topics discussed are bla and this is a paragraph bla bla bla.
```

However, this works fine:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
.... image code whatever
\end{wrapfigure}
The cat sat on the mat. \citet{key} published bla and bla and the topics discussed are bla and this is a paragraph bla bla bla.
```

Comment: Just wondering: especially when you have little time you should provide an MWE as it usually increases the chances of getting a fast answer significantly. Also adding the 10 or so missing lines to complete the code snippet should've taken no more 2 minutes...?

Comment: Wasn't a priority for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution: add a `\leavevmode`. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, draft]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth:ct,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volumes = {5},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  address = {Reading, Mass.},
  year =  {{1984--1986}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{wrapfig, natbib}

\newcommand\test{\citet{knuth:ct} published bla and bla and the topics
  discussed are bla and this is a paragraph bla bla bla.\space}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\rule{0.49\textwidth}{3cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\test \test \test \test \test

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\rule{0.49\textwidth}{3cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
The cat sat on the mat.
\test \test \test \test \test

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\rule{0.49\textwidth}{3cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\leavevmode \test \test \test \test \test

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: (From a comment.) `\leavevmode` is, according to *TeX by Topic*, a macro to switch to horizontal mode if necessary.  So, I suppose you could patch your `\citet` command to include a `\leavevmode`, but I'm not sure if it wouldn't have unforeseen consequences elsewhere; I can't think of where, but others can certainly answer that better than I can.  Anyway, this works for this example:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\citet}{\leavevmode}%
  {\typeout{*****  patching \string\citet\space succeeded !! *****}}%
  {\typeout{*****  patching \string\citet\space failed !!  *****}}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason for not redefining the cite commands so that the `\leavevmode` is used every time it is called?, sorry but I do not know enough about it, or the possible consequences.

Comment: @ADP -- See the revised answer.